# If I want to trigger an external API call when a button is pressed - controller or model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to update my data via a call to an external API when a button is pressed.

Should I put the logic in my controller or in my model?

Or rather, which logic should go in the controller versus which should go in the model.

Basically, I want to check to see if new records have been created on the external service - if there are new ones, then I want to pull those and create a new record on my side.

If not, then just ignore it and move on.

What's the best way to approach this?

Code samples would help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a class or module under `lib` that would handle all the core API call, and call that in the model.

So I would do something like the following. Create the file like `lib/tag_fetcher.rb` :

```
module TagFetcher

  def self.fetch_tags(...)
    # adress some API to fetch the tags
  end
end
```

and then in your model write something like

```
def self.update_tags
  api_result = TagFetcher.fetch_tags
  # do your stuff here
end
```

(of course: you should think of more relevant names for your case)

Reasons to do it this way:

- testability: you can test the fetching and the update in isolation from each other
- cleaner code: fetching tags is not the responsability of the model (single responsability principle)
- if the API would somehow change, or you would call a different API with the same service, the change could be minimal

HTH.

Comment: Perfect...this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks very much. I guess the last piece is, how do I trigger `TagFetcher` via a button? i.e. I want to be able to press a button on a view and it updates the db via `update_tags` & `TagFetcher`. Btw, what does `HTH` stand for? Also, why would I not do this inside `app/helpers/`? Are those just for my views?

Comment: HTH="hope this helps" :)  Yes, 'app/helpers' is just helper-code for views, there is no state in a helper. Usually I use that for small methods that help me build the html. Your button should link to some controller+action, which would then call the `update_tags`. If you struggle with these really-really basic concepts, I advise you to pick up a rails book. The best way to get the basics.

Comment: Heh...last I checked, most 'basic' rails books don't teach you how to abstract concerns like this. I just may pick up a book though, you may be right.